# I need to watch a input field using angular js which is of array type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to watch the value on this field

```
<input type="number" ng-model="table.fields[$index].item_count" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
```

And created this in watch

```
$scope.$watch('table.fields[$index].item_count', function(){
    console.log("newValue"+newValue);
    console.log("oldValue"+oldValue);
    });
```

The above seems correct but I'm getting the value as udefined on the console.

Comment: `function(newValue, oldValue){`

Comment: Why don't you use ng-change instead?

Comment: that watch doesn't make sense.  `$index` is the indexer for an element's position in `ng-repeat`, it has no context in JavaScript.  Inside your controller, `$index` will be undefined, and so you will always be watching `table.fields[undefined].item_count`, which clearly won't work.  if `ng-change` on the input isn't a possibility, then you will have to watch the entire array for changes, which is a **very expensive** operation.

Comment: incidentally, it's odd that you are referring to a property from `ng-model` in an array syntax and using `$index`, since `$index` **is not the item's position in the array**, it is the position of the item in the `ng-repeat` only.   This is not guaranteed to be the same, especially if filters are applied to your data, and can lead to some nasty, hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 $scope.$watch('table.fields', function (newValue, oldValue) {
 if(newValue&&oldValue&&newValue.length==oldValue.length){
   for(var i=0;i<newValue.length;i++){
     if(newValue[i].item_count!=oldValue[i].item_count){
       console.log('newValue'+newValue[i].item_count); 
       console.log('oldValue'+oldValue[i].item_count); 
     }
   }
 }
},true);
```

Comment: Still nothing is being printed in my console only the string newValue and oldValue is being printed at the start of my application in my console any idea

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav  what's $index is?

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav  what's about `$scope.$watch('table.fields',function(newValue,oldValue,true))` , then get filed item_count by other way

Comment: here my updated plunker link plnkr.co/edit/Z77HpJlonL71j2CDstXq

Comment: the how I can get the old and new value at once so that I can add that values

Comment: the link which u gave its not working, actually its not getting the oldvalue it's printing all the values as a new value only, oldvalue is undefined

Comment: if you only input one time,oldvalue  is undefined.please more input more value. then you will see   
   `newValue5  
    oldValueundefined  
    newValue55  
    oldValue5  
    newValue555  
    oldValue55  
`

Comment: no am not getting it, am getting old value as undefined, if I enter 5 oldvalue  is undefined newvalue is 5 again if I enter 6 new value is 6 old value is undefined please check you plunker

Comment: before enter 6 , if you  deleted 5?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `newValue` and `oldValue` arguments in the function:

```
    $scope.$watch('table.fields[$index].item_count', function(newValue, oldValue){
    ...
```

Comment: Still nothing is being printed in my console only the string newValue and oldValue is being printed at the start of my application in my console

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: this is my plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/fYBiMjFhcZnNfk7RXmsk

am getting value undefined

Comment: here my updated plunker link plnkr.co/edit/Z77HpJlonL71j2CDstXq

Answer (score 0):

You can use different controller for ng-repeat part to get the current scope of list.

**HTML Part**

```
<div ng-controller='mainController'>
    <div ng-repeat="field in table.fields" ng-controller="tableController">
        <input type="number" ng-model="field.item_count" 
        value = "{{field.item_count}}"class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" 
        placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular Part**

```
app.controller('mainController',function($scope){

$scope.table = {};
$scope.table.fields = [
    {item_count: 222 },
    {item_count: 454 },
    {item_count: 676 },
    {item_count: 344 },
    {item_count: 986 }
 ];
});

app.controller('tableController', function ($scope) {
$scope.$watch('field.item_count', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('newValue: ' + newValue);
  console.log('oldValue: ' + oldValue);
});});
```

Comment: this is my plunker link plnkr.co/edit/fYBiMjFhcZnNfk7RXmsk am getting value undefined –

Comment: I was unable to open your plunker for some reason related to proxy in my pc.

I have prepared a fiddle look once [http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/834/](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/834/)
If you have problem please make a fiddle(plunker is giving me problem)

Comment: can you give fiddle link ?? plunkr not working for me

Comment: Do u get any error click on run after going to the pluker page from the link which I gave

Comment: no no..there is no error in codes..connection is resetting. I'm not able to start any plukr

Comment: you can see the code right, if yes means click run button, I have shared that link to couple of members they said it working

Comment: Check [https://jsfiddle.net/oh8goto0/3/] (https://jsfiddle.net/oh8goto0/3/)

Updated fiddle: (first time value will be undefined. )

Comment: I have added ' ng-controller="tableController" ' in your '<fieldset >' tag. & moved $watch expression in that controller. It will work according to current scope of ng-repeat. Check if working

Comment: actually its printing both old and new value the same value not the different one

Comment: actually in alert & console.log section both value were 'newValue' ;)
a overlooked mistake I guess.
Check This one : [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/oh8goto0/5/)

Comment: still the same one I have also tried this code previously the same what I got is you are getting now I  need to get both the old and new value differently but for the first time am getting undefined, I I add a field when I type a number am getting new value and also for old value undefined thats okay but if I add another value I should get the old value as my previous field value but am getting undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100380/discussion-between-amarmishra-and-m-balajivaishnav).